# ut8 meta tag doesnt show special chars in php site

Tags: php, html, utf-8

Iam using a php web site which ia by default has iso-8859-1 header type in html page. I had changed it to utf-8  then the special characters were showing in different way [ not rendering properly]

Edit: 
Header:

```
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
```

echoing the string which is showing as mentioned below:

```
1.  Nytt filter f�r v�lja spr�k och aktiva Medarbetare
```

May i know the reason.

Thanks

Comment: perhaps because it should be `utf-8` instead of `utf8`

Comment: thanks for ur reply, i know about that its typo error. utf-8

Comment: Is your .php file utf-8 ? What about database encoding? (if any)

Comment: Perhaps then show us the headers, and indicate if the data you're echoing is utf-8 (whether from a database or from straight echoing of strings in the php code)

Comment: does your db has same encoding, probably??

Comment: @MarkBaker header tag added and yes im echoing the string

Comment: Either your server is overwriting the meta charset via a different charset in the Content-Type header (which takes precedence over the meta value) – or your content is not actually encoded in UTF-8.

Comment: If you're echoing a string defined in your php script, is your php file encoded as utf-8?

Comment: i tried to change utf-8 encode options in notepad++, still its not wokring

Answer (score 1):

If you see the UNICODE REPLACEMENT CHARACTER �, that means the browser is interpreting the document as UTF-8 (or at least as *some* Unicode encoding). The � character means that the byte sequence at this spot could not be processed correctly as Unicode character. This means the encoding *declaration*, the `<meta>` tag, works just fine as it should, but **your document is not actually UTF-8 encoded.**

The `<meta>` tag just tells the browser what encoding the document is supposedly in, so the browser can parse it correctly. If you tell the browser the document is encoded in UTF-8, then you need to actually encode the document in UTF-8! Just changing the meta tag doesn't magically transform the document into another encoding.

Also see [UTF-8 all the way through](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/279170/utf-8-all-the-way-through).

Comment: thanks for your reply, iam using notepad++ and i changed encode type to utf-8 also with meta tag. but still browser � showing these chars

Comment: How exactly did you "change encode type to utf-8"? If you check in your browser in the *View* menu under *Encoding* and explicitly select UTF-8, does it still look that way? If so, the file is *not* actually UTF-8 encoded.

Comment: in editor Menu -> Encodeing -> UTF8 then string has became like this : tillXE4nglig  otherwise it was like this :tillgänglig

Comment: I don't know Notepad++, but this sounds wrong. What you apparently did was tell Notepad++ to *interpret* your document in UTF-8, but not to change its encoding to UTF-8. The same way you incorrectly told the browser to interpret a document which isn't UTF-8 as UTF-8. Use *File → Save As...* and choose UTF-8 there, or something along those lines. The editor still must display the characters correctly, if they're already screwed up in the editor you're doing it wrong.